# 'g++' is not recognized even after adding it to System Path Variable

Tags: c++, installation, g++, mingw

I have installed the MinGW C++ Compiler. 
[image]

I have added it to System Path Variable as well. 
[image]

And the command works when I am in that directory. 
[image]

However, when I run the command in some other directory, I get the error. 
[image]

I have restarted my system a couple of times just in case but it still doesn't work.

Comment: The rest of the elements are single paths per line, but you have two per line plus semicolons, maybe that's the issue? Also did you restart the console after making the changes?

Comment: Each line is one path, so you have added one path that is "C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks a lot! I separated them into two and it worked.